# Why does unwrapping a cloned Rc cause a panic?

Tags: rust, reference-counting, panic

Why does this code panic on line 7? Shouldn't foo_unwrapped be Some(3) on line 5 instead of None?

```
use std::rc::Rc;
fn main()
{
    let foo: Rc<i32> = Rc::new(3);
    let mut foo_cloned = Rc::clone(&foo);
    let mut foo_unwrapped = Rc::get_mut(&mut foo_cloned).unwrap();  
    foo_unwrapped = &mut 42;
}
```

Comment: I said I urge to downvote it, not that I downvoted it ;) But I see your point here. In my opinion, the doc clearly states when it returns `None` and when it does return `Some(_)`, so I ask myself the question whether you read the doc in the first place (you said yes). So your title ask, why it does panic -> because of the `unwrap`. Why is there a `None` value -> the doc states it, because you have more than one Rc that points to the same value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the `Rc` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.get_mut) (emphasis mine)

> ```
> pub fn get_mut(this: &mut Rc<T>) -> Option<&mut T>
> ```
>
> Returns a mutable reference into the given `Rc`, if there are no other `Rc` or `Weak` pointers to the same allocation.
>
> **Returns `None` otherwise, because it is not safe to mutate a shared value.**
>
> See also `make_mut`, which will clone the inner value when there are other pointers.

You have two `Rc` pointers pointing to the same data (namely, `foo` and `foo_cloned`), so it's not safe to get a mutable reference to the data.

`Rc` isn't a magic trick to get out of Rust's borrowing semantics. Rust is still a single-ownership language and still enforces all of the same protections; it's just that in the case of `Rc`, the enforcement happens at runtime rather than compile-time.